# What is MergeRootFrame in FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-framelayout

In `FrameLayout` of `XML` we have an attribute by name `tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"`, what is `MergeRootFrame` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's for the [Lint tool](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint). You're asking it to ignore (i.e. not show warnings for) the "MergeRootFrame" rule:

> `"MergeRootFrame": Checks whether a root <FrameLayout> can be replaced with a <merge> tag`

Answer (score 4):

`<tools>` attributes is basically used as a shortcut to store information and facilitating Android platform with required conditions without further computation. 
`"tools:ignore"` is a statement which actually is telling `Lint` tool to ignore "issue id" - `"MergeRootFrame"`.

based on `ipavl's` answer - `<merge>` tag is is basically used to remove multiple layers of viewgroups which are not required / degrades UI performance. this statement basically asks `Lint` to ignore warnings where, there are multiple redundant `<framelayout>`'s and this could be further optimized my replacing it with `<merge>`

This is explained here, beautifully - [Warning: This <FrameLayout> can be replaced with a <merge> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488027/warning-this-framelayout-can-be-replaced-with-a-merge-tag)

Bottom line: Technically you are asking `Lint` to ignore warnings of this kind

### Links:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes ,
https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html